# Flex 3 - List - checkbox itemrenderer enabled property

Tags: apache-flex, list, checkbox, adobe, itemrenderer

I have a list that uses a checkbox itemrenderer.  The dataprovider is a collection of people.  When I load the data from a file, each list item shows the person's name (last, first -- labelFunction), and the checkbox's selected property shows the person's **included property**.  I.e.,

Smith, Doug - [x]
Williams, Bob - [ ]
Morris, Anne - [x]

However, each person also has an **active** property.  I want to disable the checkbox for people who are inactive (meaning, "you can't include inactive people").  I have tried several methods to get this to work, including what's suggested here http://forums.adobe.com/thread/416786 to do the same thing in a datagrid.  However, none of them work and all the checkboxes are enabled regardless of the person's **active** status.  Here is my basic code:

```
<mx:List id="peopleIncludedList"
     dataProvider="{someProvider}"
     labelFunction="peopleLabelFunction">
     <mx:itemRenderer>
          <mx:Component>
               <mx:CheckBox change="onChange(event)"
                    selected="{outerDocument.isIncluded(data)}">
                    <mx:Script>
                         <![CDATA[

                              private function onChange(e:Event):void
                              {
                                   ...
                              }
                         ]]>
                    </mx:Script>
               </mx:CheckBox>
          </mx:Component>
     </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:List>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

-- Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since stackoverflow only notifies me daily of new answers, I wasn't actively looking at this thread, and was more involved on the Adobe boards.  Anyway, found a solution.  Reference it here http://forums.adobe.com/message/3267367.  Thanks everyone for your suggestions and helpfulness!

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a crack at it, but sometimes it is hard to tell without sample data.

First, don't reference the outerDocument in arenderer, and don't use binding, instead listen to the dataChange event

```
<mx:List id="peopleIncludedList"
     dataProvider="{someProvider}"
     labelFunction="peopleLabelFunction">
     <mx:itemRenderer>
          <mx:Component>
               <mx:CheckBox change="onChange(event)" dataChange="onDataChange()">
                    <mx:Script>
                         <![CDATA[

                              private function onChange(e:Event):void
                              {
                                  // not sure what this method is doing
                              }
private function onDataChange():void{
 this.selected = isIncluded(data); // whatever your processing is
 if(data.person.active == true){
   this.enabled = true;
 } else {
   this.enabled = false;
 }
}
                         ]]>
                    </mx:Script>
               </mx:CheckBox>
          </mx:Component>
     </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:List>
```

Comment: would he not just get away with <mx:CheckBox enabled={data.person.active} ... > and not worry about the data change events? Assuming person and active are bindable of course...

Comment: @Gregor Kiddie I'm not sure; I think he has two issues; checking / unchecking the CheckBox and enabling / disabling it. I Guess he could do both w/ bindig assuming they relate to properties on the data object.  The fact that he was calling a method for selected leaves that assumption ambigious.  Binding in an itemRenderer will cause issues eventually, though.

Comment: @Jeff. I surely will, but having some bits of the answer using binding, and some bits not confuses the issue I think. Using the ClassFactory for setting values for the isIncluded(...) stuff would be a better way of doing that bit for example. It's the bigger question! Try and answer peoples questions so they can continue, or educate them as how to do it better in the first place...

Comment: @Gregor Kiddie I modified my answer to remove the binding on the checkbox.  It's just something I missed in my cut and paste job of the original code.  The code was already changing the selected value in the onDataChange method.   As far as I knew, I do try to answer people's questions so they can continue and educate them on how to do it better; I'm sorry if you feel I do otherwise.

Comment: Woah... that wasn't a dig! It was a musing for myself, cos I'm guilty of the first too often (answering the question as put rather than re-educating). Probably why your Rep is much higher than mine ;)

Comment: @Gregor Kiddie No offense taken. ;) I think the only reason my rep is higher than you is I've answered more questions. ( 495 vs your 174 ).